# Sculpt tool not working with head

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I'm currently trying to sculpt out a head, but I can't sculpt the head itself. It lets me sculpt the neck, but anything else is unable to be sculpted.

The part circled in yellow can't be sculpted, but the part in red can. How do I make it so every part can be sculpted?[image]

Comment: if they are 2 separate objects you can press Alt Q to switch from one to the other

Comment: Have you activated the mask? (the head looks a bit darker) Try the menu *Mask > Clear Mask* to remove it. Masked mesh is protected and can not be modified.